# Change column name with tq_get() in Tidyquant

Tags: r, tidyverse, tidyquant

I'm using the `tq_get()` function in Tidyquant to retrieve economic data from FRED:

```
library(tidyquant)
library(tidyverse)

consumer_price_index <- 'CPIAUCSL'

start_date <- as.Date('2022-01-01')
end_date <- as.Date('2022-03-31')

cpi <- tq_get(consumer_price_index,
               from = start_date,
               to = end_date,
               get = 'economic.data')

cpi

# A tibble: 3 x 3
  symbol   date       price
  <chr>    <date>     <dbl>
1 CPIAUCSL 2022-01-01  282.
2 CPIAUCSL 2022-02-01  284.
3 CPIAUCSL 2022-03-01  288.
```

How do I change the name of the `price` column to `cpi`?

The desired tibble would look as follows:

```
# A tibble: 3 x 3
  symbol   date        cpi
  <chr>    <date>     <dbl>
1 CPIAUCSL 2022-01-01  282.
2 CPIAUCSL 2022-02-01  284.
3 CPIAUCSL 2022-03-01  288.
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use `rename` from `dplyr`

```
cpi <- tq_get(consumer_price_index,
              from = start_date,
              to = end_date,
              get = 'economic.data') %>% 
  rename(cpi = price)

# A tibble: 3 × 3
  symbol   date         cpi
  <chr>    <date>     <dbl>
1 CPIAUCSL 2022-01-01  282.
2 CPIAUCSL 2022-02-01  284.
3 CPIAUCSL 2022-03-01  288.
```

Or just use `colnames` from `base`

```
colnames(cpi)<- c("symbol", "date", "cpi")
```

Answer (score 1):

Using column number:

```
names(cpi)[3] <- "cpi"
cpi

# A tibble: 3 x 3
  symbol   date         cpi
  <chr>    <date>     <dbl>
1 CPIAUCSL 2022-01-01  282.
2 CPIAUCSL 2022-02-01  284.
3 CPIAUCSL 2022-03-01  288.
```